# use LIKE in powerapp with % and _

Tags: powerapps

Is there any eqivalent of LIKE option in PowerApp that allow use sql special characters like "%" or "_" in Search or Filter to find any records?

I would like to write in search: "DAP%55" and find all redords like: 
DAPAAA55
DAPoooo55
... and so on...

- eqivalent to 
  SELECT * FROM sth WHERE name like 'DAP%55'

Is that possoble?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways that you can do that:

- `Filter(<data source name>, StartsWith(name, "DAP"), EndsWith(name, "55"))`

  - This case may work for the pattern in your example, but not for things more complex such as "D_P%55"
- `Filter(<data source name>, IsMatch(name, "DAP.+55"))`

  - The [IsMatch function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-ismatch) is more generic and you can use any regular expressions. This function may not be delegated to the server, so it will be an issue if you need to filter over a large data source.